# execute a function on each element that has a certain class (.js only)

Tags: javascript, for-loop

As a beginner I'm having problems with logic.

I have this html with ids that i'm not allowed to change, so i won't be able to work with unique ids like infoPrice1,infoPrice2... And what i have to do is to verify if the product has a promotion and create a flag with a class that is already in use in other cases. I checked the promo case by verifying if the priceFrom id exists (it will only exists in this cases).Then I treated the values ​​to know the discount percentage and then write the value in the HTML.

I finally found a way to create a list with elements that have the class product by using getElementsByClassName (which works when I give a console.log[i] to check the elements), but when I pass the function that i created to make the calculations and insert the elements in, it seems to run only on the first element.

I want it to run the function in each element with the class "product". verifying if it has a promo, making the math to create the html element and putting the element in if it have a promo (note tha it may not have when the id priceFrom doesnt exists in the product div)

below the complete code with commented js for better understanding:

```js
function write() {
  var infoPrice = document.getElementById("infoPrice");
  var temPromocao = infoPrice.querySelector("#priceFrom");

  if (temPromocao !== null) {
    //check if element with id priceFrom exists
    var valorDe = document.getElementById("priceFrom").innerText.replace("R$ ", "");
    var valorPor = document.getElementById("bestPrice").innerText.replace("R$ ", "");
    //get values like R$00,00 and returns only  00,00
    var valorIntDe = Number.parseFloat(valorDe.replace(",", "."));
    var valorIntPor = Number.parseFloat(valorPor.replace(",", "."));
    //turns values in number so i can make the calcs = 00.00
    var desconto = Math.round(((valorIntDe - valorIntPor) / valorIntDe) * 100);
    //percentage calculation
    var recebeP = document.getElementById("flagArea");
    recebeP.innerHTML = "<p id='flagBox' class='flag'>-" + (desconto) +"%</p>";
    //create element in html
  };
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(a) {
  var products = document.getElementsByClassName("product");

  for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    write(products[i]);
    console.log(products[i].innerHTML)
  }
  //My idea was that this would apply the function on each element with the product class
});
```

```css
.product {
  border: 1px solid #e41021;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.fac-product__content__info__price__from {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
}

.flag-area p {
  background-color: #e41021;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>fac-vtex-cms-auto-flag</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="flag-area" id="flagArea">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div id="infoPrice" class="fac-product__content__info__price">
      <p>Product 1</p>
      <span class="fac-product__content__info__price__from">
          <p class="fac-product__content__info__price__from__txt">Old price:</p>
          <p
            id="priceFrom"
            class="fac-product__content__info__price__from__price"
          >
            R$ 149,00
          </p>
          <p class="fac-product__content__info__price__from__txt">Sale:</p>
        </span>
      <span id="bestPrice" class="fac-product__content__info__price__sale-price">R$ 50,00</span
        >
        <em class="fac-product__content__info__price__installment">
          <em>in cash</em>
        </em>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
      <div class="flag-area" id="flagArea"></div>
      <p>Product 2</p>
      <div id="infoPrice" class="fac-product__content__info__price">
        <span class="fac-product__content__info__price__from">
          <p class="fac-product__content__info__price__from__txt">Old price:</p>
          <p
            id="priceFrom"
            class="fac-product__content__info__price__from__price"
          >
            R$ 10,00
          </p>
          <p class="fac-product__content__info__price__from__txt">Sale:</p>
        </span>
      <span id="bestPrice" class="fac-product__content__info__price__sale-price">R$ 5,00</span
        >
        <em class="fac-product__content__info__price__installment">
          <em>in cash</em>
        </em>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `write()` function is missing a parameter variable.

Comment: IDs need to be unique in the document, you can't use the same ID for multiple elements. Either use class names or give all the elements unique IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `write()` function needs to use its parameter to access the elements in that product.

It can use `querySelector()` to select elements with a class inside the product div.

```js
function write(product) {
  var infoPrice = product.querySelector(".fac-product__content__info__price");
  var temPromocao = infoPrice.querySelector(".fac-product__content__info__price__from__price");

  if (temPromocao !== null) {
    var valorDe = temPromocao.innerText.replace("R$ ", "");
    var valorPor = infoPrice.querySelector(".fac-product__content__info__price__sale-price").innerText.replace("R$ ", "");
    //get values like R$00,00 and returns only  00,00
    var valorIntDe = Number.parseFloat(valorDe.replace(",", "."));
    var valorIntPor = Number.parseFloat(valorPor.replace(",", "."));
    //turns values in number so i can make the calcs = 00.00
    var desconto = Math.round(((valorIntDe - valorIntPor) / valorIntDe) * 100);
    //percentage calculation
    var recebeP = product.querySelector(".flag-area");
    recebeP.innerHTML = `<p id="flagBox" class="flag">-${desconto}%</p>`;
    //create element in html
  };
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(a) {
  var products = document.getElementsByClassName("product");

  for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    write(products[i]);
  }
  //My idea was that this would apply the function on each element with the product class
});
```

```css
.product {
  border: 1px solid #e41021;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.fac-product__content__info__price__from {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
}

.flag-area p {
  background-color: #e41021;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>fac-vtex-cms-auto-flag</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/style.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div class="product">
    <div class="flag-area" id="flagArea">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div id="infoPrice" class="fac-product__content__info__price">
      <p>Product 1</p>
      <span class="fac-product__content__info__price__from">
        <p class="fac-product__content__info__price__from__txt">Old price:</p>
        <p id="priceFrom" class="fac-product__content__info__price__from__price">
          R$ 149,00
        </p>
        <p class="fac-product__content__info__price__from__txt">Sale:</p>
      </span>
      <span id="bestPrice" class="fac-product__content__info__price__sale-price">R$ 50,00</span>
      <em class="fac-product__content__info__price__installment">
        <em>in cash</em>
      </em>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="product">
    <div class="flag-area" id="flagArea"></div>
    <p>Product 2</p>
    <div id="infoPrice" class="fac-product__content__info__price">
      <span class="fac-product__content__info__price__from">
          <p class="fac-product__content__info__price__from__txt">Old price:</p>
          <p id="priceFrom" class="fac-product__content__info__price__from__price">
            R$ 10,00
          </p>
          <p class="fac-product__content__info__price__from__txt">Sale:</p>
        </span>
      <span id="bestPrice" class="fac-product__content__info__price__sale-price">R$ 5,00</span>
      <em class="fac-product__content__info__price__installment">
        <em>in cash</em>
      </em>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: unfortunately with this I get the following error: "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')",

here: `var recebeP = infoPrice.querySelector(".flag-area");
      recebeP.innerHTML = "<p id='flagBox' class='flag'>-" + (desconto) +"%</p>";`

Comment: Sorry about that. `.flag-area` is in `product`, not `infoPrice`.